# A puppet configuration style for users

Tags: users, configure, active-directory, puppet

I want to set a configuration managment utility for users, like puppet but for users, I need to install one package or another  or apply one manifest (in puppet) in order of the user that is logged in the computer or its belonging to a group, Is there any way of doing this?

The way of logging users is with a Microsoft AD

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you want to achieve - do you want to apply user-specific configuration changes? Can you give us a more detailed example of what you want to do?

Comment: Yes, exactly I want to apply user-specific configuration based on groups, or usernames, but in a centralized way